# Cannot acces to MarkovCohort() function

Tags: r, simulation, markov

I am trying to replicate the following tutorial (https://devinincerti.com/2015/10/15/markov_cohort.html)

Unfortunately, I am not able to find out where the package that enables working with the `MarkovCohort()` function comes from. I have just pasted in the main R script the following code

```
source("_rmd-posts/markov.R")
```

Getting the following error

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file '_rmd-posts/markov.R': No such file or directory
```

Could you please suggest what could I do to get to that sourc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon looking, the `markov.R` file is in his `Github` repository,

https://github.com/dincerti/dincerti.github.io/blob/master/_rmd-posts/markov.R

Here is his repository in case there would be more reference to it.

https://github.com/dincerti/dincerti.github.io

Comment: Thank you so much. Possibly you might be an expert on the Markov model. Could you please have a look at the following question about this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73996454/how-to-figure-building-criteria-of-markov-matrix